# Why Eclipse does not include annotations when implementing methods from a Java interface?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, annotations

The following interface:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Action;

public interface AnnotationsTestInterface {
    @Action
    public void annotatedMethod();
}
```

And an implementing class:

```
public class Impl implements AnnotationsTestInterface {}
```

At this point Eclipse asks me to add unimplemented methods (I choose this) or make the class abstract.

After the addition the class looks like this:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Action;

public class Impl implements AnnotationsTestInterface {

    @Override
    @Action
    public void annotatedMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

It correctly writes the Action annotation.

On another Eclipse instance (same version, different user) the "Add unimplemented methods" action results in this (no `@Action` annotation):

```
public class Impl implements AnnotationsTestInterface {

    @Override
    public void annotatedMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Is there an option somewhere that deals with this?

Note that the execution environment is set on Java SE 6, with a JDK 6.

Comment: Do both Eclipse instances operate with the same `workspace`?  If not, how is source code shared and how do you know that they run exactly the same code?

Comment: Not the same workspace. Code is replicated by hand, just to test. I feel there should be some setting.

Comment: Can you run a file comparison (between the two versions of your java files? Just to be sure.

Comment: File comparison of the two classes highlights the missing annotation. The interfaces are the same.

Comment: Which eclipse version are you and the other person using? Also, even if it is the same version, the use of different plugins and extensions can cause this difference.

Comment: @ferrarimarco Did you happen to find out what caused it? I'm looking to set eclipse up to import annotations from interfaces as well, and can't find anything.

Comment: Same version and release (Spring Tools Suite). I still did not figure it out.

Comment: Are the project settings Java Compiler/Annotation Processing the same in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

On eclipse, go to Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Clean Up and look around in there. If not there, look around in Code Style. You ought to find it! If I had to guess, if @Action isn't showing up in the TODO auto-generated stuff smutzle and what not, you have an old version of eclipse, or it wasn't configured to do that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I looked around but I did not find anything related. Thanks anyway.

Comment: glad I could help! :) for sure, one piece of the puzzle is fixed. Perhaps try googling something like "eclipse product @Action"

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem with the auto-generated stuff in eclipse before. In eclipse kelper 
Window>preferences>java>code style > code templates

I think that the setting you want is interface body.

This setting contains all of the default code for newly created files/methods