# Import annotations used in interface with "Add Unimplemented Methods"

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, annotations

I've searched this question everywhere. The closest I've found is here:

> [Why Eclipse does not include annotations when implementing methods from a Java interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919238/why-eclipse-does-not-include-annotations-when-implementing-methods-from-a-java-i)

What I'd like to know, is how I can include annotations used in an interface. For example:

```
package com.example.package

public interface IInterface {
    @ImportantInformation
    public void doSomethingImportant();
}
```

and then in my class:

```
package com.example.package

public class SomeClass implements IInterface { 
    @Override
    @ImportantInformation
    public void doSomethingImportant() { }
}
```

How can I have Eclipse automatically do this when I use "Add unimplemented methods.."?

I've looked through the Project Properties, and Window Properties, and can't find anything regarding this problem. I've googled it quite thoroughly, and looked through the Eclipse website.

Comment: I have the same problem, as you have seen in my question

Answer (score 0):

As I said on ferrarimarco's question, all of the default code templates are at Window>preferences>java>code style>code templates

in the kelper release (4.3.1)